# How to access the variable to which OS copies

Tags: vb.net

An interesting feature, I have seen in **jDownloader** software is any links I copy in the browser window (i.e., Ctrl+c), the copied content links automatically appears ( i.e., with out me actually pasting it) in their UI and starts downloading the content from the links, if they are valid.

I would like to program the same but am puzzled as how to access the variable to which OS copies. Please share your ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[Adam Robinson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637037/how-to-access-the-variable-to-which-os-copies/4637168#4637168) is on the right track, but is not entirely correct. I'm going to try and provide the "long" version (in contrast to his "short" version), and explain along the way where/why I think the solution that he proposes falls short of achieving your ultimate goal.

As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649016.aspx#dataxchg_Monitoring_Clipboard_Contents) he links to explains, there are three different ways of monitoring changes to the Windows clipboard, each with their own caveats:

1. Creating a clipboard viewer window that hooks into the clipboard viewer chain and receives notification messages when the contents of the clipboard have been changed by the user. (Available on all versions of Windows, but generally more difficult to code and thus discouraged for newer applications that don't have a specific need for its features.)
2. Querying the clipboard sequence number, which is a 32-bit value that changes each time the clipboard's contents are changed. Your program calls the Windows API function [`GetClipboardSequenceNumber`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649042.aspx) once and caches its value, then each time you want to check if the clipboard's contents have changed, you call that same function again and compare its return value to the value you've cached. There are two important caveats here:

   1. This function is only available in Windows 2000 and newer. This is not likely to be a problem if you're writing .NET apps, as versions of the Framework as early as 3.0 dropped W2K support.
   2. This is *not* a notification method, and you should not call this function repeatedly in a polling loop. That means that you have to *manually* call the appropriate function and compare the clipboard sequence number. You cannot use this method if you want to "listen in" and be immediately notified whenever the clipboard's contents change, as you describe in your question. The documentation is very explicit here:

      > This method is more suitable to programs which cache results based on the current clipboard contents and need to know whether the calculations are still valid before using the results from that cache. Note that this is a not a notification method and should not be used in a polling loop. To be notified when clipboard contents change, use a clipboard format listener or a clipboard viewer.
3. Creating a clipboard format listener, which registers to be notified whenever the clipboard's contents change. This is the ideal solution in your case, because it avoids the complexities of creating a clipboard viewer window (option 1), but also allows you listen in and be notified each time the clipboard's contents are changed (in contrast to option 2).

   The problem is that this is only available under Windows Vista and later. If you still have any need to target Windows XP (as most of us do), this is really not an option for you.

Therefore, from the example you provide in the question, it sounds to me like the only option available to you is option 1, creating a clipboard viewer window. The documentation goes into the gory details of how you'd set this up using the [`SetClipboardViewer` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649052.aspx) and listening for the [`WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649025.aspx) and [`WM_CHANGECBCHAIN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649019.aspx) messages. Getting this to work right can be a difficult task to do on your own, but fortunately for us .NET developers, others have already done the hard work for us. ("Others", I say, despite having *been* one of those others myself.)

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/WindowsHookLib.aspx) on CodeProject is a good example. It implements three different types of hooks: a mouse hook, a keyboard hook, and a clipboard hook. The only thing you're interested in is the clipboard hook, but you can just add a reference to the DLL in your project to start using its functionality immediately.

If you are interested in the internals of how this works and want to try coding it up yourself, [this article](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/clipboardmonitor.aspx) appears to be a fantastic description of the specific steps involved.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `My.Computer.Clipboard.GetText()` function

Also see the msdn [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28MICROSOFT.VISUALBASIC.DEVICES.COMPUTER.CLIPBOARD%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true)

Comment: But how would I know something is copied by the user to the running application ?

Comment: To be able to call that function, at first I should be able to know a copy event is generated by OS( i., right click and copy ). But how to know that is generated, to the current running application ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#dataxchg_Monitoring_Clipboard_Contents) regarding the clipboard. In particular, this link's anchor should take you to the section of the document about monitoring the clipboard contents.

The short version is that you can monitor either by polling for the sequence number and checking to see if it has changed, or you can register to listen for changes for specific clipboard contents formats. Note that the latter is only available on Vista and above, so you depending on your target platform you may have to stick with polling.

In order to use these functions, you'll have to declare a P/Invoke to the unmanaged function. Here's the [PInvoke.net page](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetClipboardSequenceNumber.html) on the GetClipboardSequenceNumber function, though the declaration here is C#, not VB.NET. The VB.NET syntax *should* be (I don't have VS in front of me to check):

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Public Shared Function GetClipboardSequenceNumber() as UInt32
End Function
```

Comment: I agree with most what you suggest, but as you say yourself, "Note that the latter is only available on Vista and above, so you depending on your target platform you may have to stick with polling." If the asker has a need to run on older versions of Windows and therefore needs to "stick with polling", the `GetClipboardSequenceNumber` function is not an option. You're going to have to do it the old school way with hooking into the clipboard viewer chain. I describe this more thoroughly in my answer.