# How to open Clip Board Viewer in Windows 7

Tags: windows, winforms

In Windows XP **clipbrd** is the command to open the clipboard viewer.we can able to see the current copied items or the Path.

In Windows 7 what is the command to open clipboard viewer..?

can any one tell me the answer..?

Comment: I don't know why Kev marked this as a possible duplicate of [using Clipboard in WP7 programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160352/using-clipboard-in-wp7-programming).  This question is about **Desktop** Windows 7, but the linked duplicate is about Windows **Phone** 7.  They are not the same at all.

Comment: @timfoden, agreed. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no clipboard viewer in Windows 7 to the best of my knowledge. In fact I think clipbrd.exe was removed from Windows at Vista. However, the XP clipbrd.exe still works fine, or there are countless 3rd party clipboard viewers to choose from.

Comment: In windows they kept.That is useful to me.using that Viewer i'm able to see last copied things.Why they removed in Windows 7..? is there any reason for that....?

Comment: In Windows XP they(Microsoft) kept.

Comment: I have no idea. When I got Vista I noticed it wasn't there. I copied across the exe from XP and forgot all about it.

Comment: Like this one: http://www.freeclipboardviewer.com/ (looked good on Google!) Or, since this is a programming Q&A site, you could always write your own clipboard viewer; details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4637808/366904).